# What are linen wraps used for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have loads of linen wrap items. Are they useful? I thought they might be used in making weapons or something. If they aren't useful, I'll just dump them all...

Comment: i heard that you can silence your armor with them somehow, wish i knew more too.

Comment: there is a mod.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't found any use yet. They didn't do anything at the forge, workbench, or grindstone, so I'm guessing they're just junk.

Comment: For what it's worth, there *was* an equivalently useless "Cloth" item in Oblivion.

Answer (score 6):

They are used for "mummification" of draugr... no use at all.

Answer (score 3):

In Vanilla Skyrim it is considered a junk item.

But there are mods that make use of it. For instance, I have a mod in which I can forge a certain kind of "armor" (more like a cloth actually) that needs one piece of linen wrap, among other materials, to be forged.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, they seem to be useless bag weight. Far too heavy for what their sell worth is. Pick up embalming tools before linen wrap. Better value per weight

Answer (score 1):

[The Skyrim Wiki article for Linen Cloth states](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Linen_Wrap):

> Linen Wrap is a miscellaneous item in [The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim). It appears to have no visible use or purpose, and is therefore regarded as a junk item. It can be found in tombs all over Skyrim, as well as various other places, near corpses, skeletons or Draugrs. It appears to have been used as part of the preservation ritual of the Draugr; the Ancient Nords were known to have been very skilled at preserving their dead.